# Getting an error from Facebook Server-Side API when sending a pixel event

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-pixel

I am trying to make use of Facebook Server-Side API to send pixel events from my server. I'm making a POST request to this endpoint:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/509380299968653/events?access_token=<SYSTEM_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN>`

and sending this payload:

`data:[
 {
    "event_name": "PageView",
    "event_time": 1586978506,
    "user_data": {
        "fbc": "fb.1.1554763741205.AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz1234567890",
        "fbp": "fb.1.1558571054389.1098115397"
    }
 }
]
,
"test_event_code":"TEST13699"`

However, I'm getting an error response from the facebook server:

`{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (events) on node type (AdsPixel)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "AaqSg_DnGvvpjI3cWCK1yPU"
   }
}`

Need help to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you are making this request against the wrong type of object. Your ID there is of an AdsPixel, but you need to create an _Offline Event Set_ first, and then use the ID of that.

Comment: That's correct @CBroe , I'm calling AdsPixel ID to send an event, like it's described in the developer docs. [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/server-side-api/get-started)

Comment: Sorry, thought this was about offline conversions.

Comment: Just in case you haven't already must upgrade calls to v7.0 or later (v.9 is the latest) before February 7th 2021.

Comment: @Merger how did u end up solving it?